# jquery closest h2 value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click button I want to get h2 value for that what I did is used a variable

```
var getClassName = $(this).closest('div').attr('class');
```

Which gave me its parent class, now I have the parent class I am trying to get its `h2`, so I have tried

```
var getH2Val= $('.'+getClassName+' h2').val();
```

Which gives me undefined value.

```
<div id="search-7" class="section-1">
    <h2>Test head</h2>
    <p>test paragraph</p>
    <p><a class="testclass" href="#test2"><button>button</button> </a></p>
</div>

<div id="search-8" class="section-1">
    <h2>Test head</h2>
    <p>test paragraph</p>
    <p><a class="testclass" href="#test2"><button>button</button>    </a></p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `closest()` logic is correct. However you then need to `find()` within that element to retrieve the `h2`. Also note that `h2` elements do not have a 'value'. To retrieve the text within them use `text()`.

Finally note that you cannot place a `button` element within an `a`, as nested clickable elements are invalid in HTML. As such I removed the `a` element in the below example as it's not needed.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var h2Text = $(this).closest('div').find('h2').text();
  console.log(h2Text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-7" class="section-1">
  <h2>Test head #1</h2>
  <p>test paragraph</p>
  <p><button>button</button></p>
</div>

<div id="search-8" class="section-1">
  <h2>Test head #2</h2>
  <p>test paragraph</p>
  <p><button>button</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I did try using an ID but missed it as it seems I was using .val() instead of text().

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, more similar to your code would be getting the parent `id` attribute (since they should be unique on a document). Note that using `class` attribute on the selector won't assure you will match a unique element.

```js
$('button').click(function()
{
    var parentID = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    var h2Text = $('#' + parentID + ' h2').text();
    console.log(h2Text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="search-7" class="section-1">
  <h2>Test head #1</h2>
  <p>test paragraph</p>
  <p><button>button</button></p>
</div>

<div id="search-8" class="section-1">
  <h2>Test head #2</h2>
  <p>test paragraph</p>
  <p><button>button</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the same code as the last, and your comment was left after

Comment: consider leave a comment up there

Comment: @LucasSanchesParanhos Yes I use the same `HTML` markup of the previous answer, but I showed a different approach, more similar to whats the OP trying to do.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I did try using an ID but missed it as it seems I was using .val() instead of text().